# how to convert a tree structure in a TSV table

Tags: json, nested, export-to-csv, jq

https://www.orthodb.org/tree

For the above json file, I want print parent-child relation in a row.

```
2759<TAB>4751
2759<TAB>33208
```

I also want to have the mapping from keys to names.

```
Eukaryota<TAB>2759
Fungi<TAB>4751
```

Note that this JSON file is a nested structure.

Could anybody let me know how to extract the info in jq? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, each child knows its own parent
so the task is trivial using `..`:

```
.. | objects | .children[]? | [.parent,.key] | @tsv
```

This produces 14746 lines.  But don't forget to use the -r command-line option.

Similarly for key-name pairs:

```
.. | objects | .children[]? | [.key, .name] | @tsv
```

Not surprisingly perhaps, this produces the same number of lines.